# Analog clock - can't delete previous image before drawing new image

Tags: c#, winforms

I am tring to put together an analog clock for a program I am currently writing.  I have the clock working with regards to the maths being correct etc, however I can't get the image from the previous tick to be deleted before generating the new image of the clock face. My code is below, I thought the `cg.Dispose();` line would do it but it doesn't want to. I have also tried disposing of the Bitmap at the end of each tick but it throws up an error there as well. Within the form all I have a pictureBox and a timer with a length of 1000ms. Also worth noting I have the code for the clockface but I just haven't included it in this!

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace ClockStreamlined
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    Graphics cg;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Enabled = true;
        bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        cg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        // Get components of the DateTime
        DateTime DateTimenow = DateTime.Now;
        double hour = DateTimenow.Hour;
        double minute = DateTimenow.Minute;
        double second = DateTimenow.Second;

        // Define increment movements for each clock hand
        double hourHandangle = (30 * hour) + (minute * 0.5);
        double minuteHandangle = 6 * minute;
        double secondHandangle = 6 * second;

        // Define xy position variables for hour minute & second
        double x_hour = 0;

        double x_minute = 0;

        double x_second = 0;

        // Calculate hour hand position

        double y_hour = -(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 50) * Math.Cos((hourHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);
        if (hourHandangle >= 0 && hourHandangle <= 180)
        {
            x_hour = (((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 50) * Math.Sin((hourHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);
        }

        else
        {   
            x_hour = -(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 50) * -1 * Math.Sin((hourHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);
        }

        // Calculate minute hand position

        double y_minute = -(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 30) * Math.Cos((minuteHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);

        if (minuteHandangle >= 0 && minuteHandangle <= 100)
        {
            x_minute = (((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 30) * Math.Sin((minuteHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);
        }
        else
        {
            x_minute = -(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 30) * -1 * Math.Sin((minuteHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);
        }

        // Calculate second hand position
        double y_second = -(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 10) * Math.Cos((secondHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);
        if (secondHandangle >= 0 && secondHandangle <= 100)
        {
            x_second = (((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 10) * Math.Sin((secondHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);
        }
        else
        {
            x_second = -(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2) - 10) * -1 * Math.Sin((secondHandangle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360);
        }

        // Get points that define hour hand
        int y_hrpoint = Convert.ToInt32(y_hour);
        int x_hrpoint = Convert.ToInt32(x_hour);

        // Get points that define minute hand
        int y_minpoint = Convert.ToInt32(y_minute);
        int x_minpoint = Convert.ToInt32(x_minute);

        // Get points that define second hand
        int x_secpoint = Convert.ToInt32(x_second);
        int y_secpoint = Convert.ToInt32(y_second);

        // Create pen
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        // Create points that define hour hand
        Point point1hr = new Point(x_hrpoint + ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2), y_hrpoint + ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2));
        Point point2hr = new Point(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2), ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2));

        // Create points that define minute hand
        Point point1min = new Point(x_minpoint + ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2), y_minpoint + ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2));
        Point point2min = new Point(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2), ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2));

        // Create points that define second hand
        Point point1sec = new Point(x_secpoint + ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2), y_secpoint + ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2));
        Point point2sec = new Point(((pictureBox1.Width) / 2), ((pictureBox1.Width) / 2));

        // Draw to Bitmap
        // Draw line to screen.
        cg.DrawLine(blackPen, point1hr, point2hr);
        cg.DrawLine(blackPen, point1min, point2min);
        cg.DrawLine(blackPen, point1sec, point2sec);
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        cg.Dispose();
        Invalidate();

    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `bmp` a local variable in the `timer1_Tick` function and create the `bmp` Bitmap each time at the beginning of `timer1_Tick`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);;
        Graphics cg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        // your other code from timer1_Tick
        // Get components of the DateTime
        DateTime DateTimenow = DateTime.Now;
        double hour = DateTimenow.Hour;
        double minute = DateTimenow.Minute;
        double second = DateTimenow.Second;

        // ....

        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        cg.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @acodeoficeandfire Mark it as the answer if it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

To clear the previous drawing You need to call `cg.Clear(Color.White)` with whatever background color you want.

It would also be better for your timer tick to invalid the panel, then for the `OnPaint` event of the panel to do the actual drawing.  You also don't actually need to use a Bitmap.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Compute hand positions.
    // ...


    // Clear the previous drawing.
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

    // Create pen, draw the hands.
    using (Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1hr, point2hr);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1min, point2min);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1sec, point2sec);
    }
}
```